# React Native Storybook run packager on different port

Tags: react-native, storybook

Storybook packager's default port is 8081.
This is the same port that is being used by React Native packager.

Is there any way to change the port for the Storybook packager so I could have both packagers run simultaneity?

Please note that running the command "npm run storybook -p 8082" will only change the served storybook page but not the packager port.

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble too getting Storybook to work with React Native. I tried this command and everything workeded as intended:

`adb reverse tcp:7007 tcp:7007`